# Rails New SampleApp Hangs forever after Run Bundle Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

While creating new sample project My Rails New Sample hangs forever and does not give controll back to me.

On pressing <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> its asks for terminating Batch job...

I am new to ruby On Rails....Please help

```
C:\Sites>rails new MySample2
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      '
      ' 
      ' 
      And So on....at the end its showls like

      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run bundle install
      DL is deprecated,please use fiddle
```

Comment: Thanks...it got resolved....!!!

Comment: Great but what did you do? I have the same problem.

Comment: Change Https:// to Http://

Comment: Sorry For the late reply...Just change it in the Gemfile

Comment: Great thanks. It seems the answer below was right. Mark it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bundler cannot download gems. Add this config

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

it change any git://.. source to https:// on the fly